# Unable to run powershell script with desired user for highest previligies

Tags: powershell, ansible

We have some executeable programs on windows which we must run as administrator. To invoke those program i have written a powershell script. This runs perfectly fine if i logon to the windows and open powershell as admin and run the script. However i am trying to achieve the same using ansible playbook but the playbook runs all other powershell script without any issue. But when it comes to the executeable it just hangs the pipeline. I am so struggling with this. here is my ansible pipeline. The ansible pipeline itself has the same user with which i logon to the windows and run the script manually. That user is an administrator user but has a different name then admin. For all other powershell scripts i have not mentioned any username or become keywords, they just work because all other script do not need run as admin. Let me know please how can i fix this

```
- hosts: all 
  become_method: runas
  tasks:

  - name: Run startup scripts with elevated privileges
    win_command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Program Files\setup\app_startup_script.ps1" 
    become: yes
    become_user: my-user
    ansible_become_password: password
```